# How do i fix my c# binary search algorithm?

Tags: c#, binary-search

I'm trying to implement a binary search algorithm in my program, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my code:

```
public static void Search(float[] array, float key)
    {
        int min = 0; 
        int max = array.Length - 1;
        int mid = 0;

        do
        {
            mid = (min + max) / 2;

            if (key > array[mid])
            {
                min = mid + 1; 
            }

            if (key < array[mid])
            {
                max = mid - 1; 
            }

            if (key == array[mid])
                Console.WriteLine($"The item, {key} was found at index {mid} of the array");
        } while (min <= max);
```

(The array that I'm using is sorted)
I just get a blank console and it never seems to find a result.
What do I do to fix it?

Thanks

UPDATE: 
I've created the float[] from a txt file as shown below:

```
float[] floats = (File.ReadAllLines(@"floats.txt")).Where(s => s != String.Empty).Select(s => float.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

[Here's the contents of floats.txt (link to pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/dnGej95i)

Here's the line used to test if the algorithm works:

```
Search(floats, -2.4439f);
```

(Also, I sort the array before trying to search it)

Comment: What does your array look like, and what is the key? Maybe key doesn't exist in the array.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: Is this for learning purposes?

Comment: Is your input array sorted?

Comment: @Jon It's an array of 256 floats, and I'm using a key that is definatly in the array.

Comment: @Magnus It's for learning, yes

Comment: @jdweng yes, the array is sorted

Comment: Please include the code that initializes the array and calls the Search function. Then we can reproduce and help you.

Comment: Comparing floats can be tricky, are you SURE the exact key is in the array, and not something very close. Instead of ==, you could try a comparison such as Math.Abs(key - array[mid]) < 0.0001 or something. Floats are tricky to work with for equality.

Comment: Btw, I tested your code and it works fine with my test array of about 20 floats. Check above and see if that works.

Comment: If the built in `Array.BinarySearch(array, key)` cant find it either it is probably a floating point issue.

Comment: while (min <= max)

The loop will continue forever when min = max

Comment: Please see my answer which works for the input array you provided. You didn't sort the array before you did the search.

Answer (score 0):

This code actually works for me, using the input file you provided. My guess is you're not sorting the array first:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Read in floats from input file
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "input.txt"));
        var floats = new List<float>();
        foreach (var l in lines)
        {
            if (float.TryParse(l, out var result))
            {
                floats.Add(result);
            }
        }

        var array = floats.OrderBy(f => f).ToArray();
        float key = -2.4439f;

        Search(array, key);
    }

    public static void Search(float[] array, float key)
    {
        int min = 0;
        int max = array.Length - 1;
        int mid = 0;

        do
        {
            mid = (min + max) / 2;

            if (key > array[mid])
            {
                min = mid + 1;
            }

            if (key < array[mid])
            {
                max = mid - 1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Checking {array[mid]}");
            if (key == array[mid])
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The item, {key} was found at index {mid} of the array");
                break;
            }
        } while (min <= max);
    }
```

This is the output:

```
The item, -2.4439 was found at index 146 of the array
```

Comment: I'm sorting first too, but am just greeted with a black console

Comment: Run my code, it works. You just need to step through your code and debug it. Maybe compare the floats[] array to mine? How are you sorting the float array in your example?

Answer (score -2):

Binary search is a perfect candidate for a recursive function.
Maybe you could try something like this:

```
public static void Search(float[] array, float key, int? min = null, int? max = null)
    {
        if (!min.HasValue)
        {
            min = 0;
        }
        if (!max.HasValue)
        {
            max = array.Length - 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Searching from {0} to {1}", min.Value, max.Value));

        if (min.Value >= max.Value)
        {
            if (array[min.Value] == key)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The item, {0} was found at index {1} of the array", key, min.Value));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int mid = (max.Value - min.Value) / 2;
            if (mid < 1)
            {
                mid = 1;
            }
            Search(array, key, min, min.Value + mid - 1);
            Search(array, key, min.Value + mid, max);
        }
    }
```